# validate on field blur using jquery validate plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I need jquery validate plugin to validate all my fields on blur of the fields. Currently its validating only on submit of the form. How can I achieve this?
HTML

```
<input class=" required minlength " type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" minlength="3" maxlength="40"  />
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
form = $('#submitForm');
if (form.length) {
  form.validate({
    ignoreTitle: false,
    onfocusout: false,
    onkeyup: false,
    onclick: false,
    submitHandler: function() {
      form[0].submit();
    },      
    messages: { 
        firstName:{
            required: "First Name is required.",
            minlength: "First Name entered is invalid.",
        }
    }
    });
```

});

Comment: You have to attach an event handler for each form field for the event on blur.

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree..Thanks for ur reply..but if I have 50 fields, attaching blur events for each of the elements is difficult right? Is there a way where I can do using onfocusout or onkeyup option?

Comment: try setting `onfocusout:` to `true`

Comment: @dreamweiver..setting onfocusout:true did not work..

Comment: **Everyone, please read [the documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate) to learn the proper way to declare the `onfocusout` option**. For the ***default*** behavior, **do not** declare the option at all, because, as per docs, _"a boolean `true` is not a valid value"_ for `onfocusout`.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20861273/594235) posted on your duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$('form').find('input,select,textarea').on('blur', function() {
    $(this).validate({
        ignoreTitle: false,
        onfocusout: false,
        onkeyup: false,
        onclick: false,    
        messages: { 
            firstName:{
                required: $(this).attr('name')+" is required.",
                minlength: $(this).attr('name')+" entered is invalid.",
            }
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: @Manish..Thanks for ur reply..will making onfocusout as true work? coz I have lots of fields in the page..

Comment: It is just like as onfocusout

Comment: so if I tried onfocusout: true..but that was not working..any idea y its nt working?

Comment: Why are you not trying to use blur

Comment: Hi Manish..I tried ur solution..but its not happening..on submit even if i m nt giving any values, its moving to the next page..

Comment: Why can't anyone just [read the plugin's documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate)?  Do not wrap the `.validate()` method inside of a `blur` event handler because `.validate()` is only how the plugin is _initialized_ on the form. The `.validate()` method is **not** the _trigger_ for a validation test. Besides, you've also set the `onfocusout` option to `false` which will disable the exact behavior the OP is trying to achieve. The OP simply needs to ***remove*** the entire `onfocusout:false` option to get it to work the way he wants.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20861273/594235