# jquery validate plugin not working on blur of the fields

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I need jquery validate plugin to validate all my fields on blur of the fields. Currently its validating only on submit of the form.  This is my html
HTML

```
<input class=" required minlength aplhawithaposonly" type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" minlength="3" maxlength="40"  />
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
form = $('#submitForm');
if (form.length) {
  form.validate({
    ignoreTitle: false,
    onfocusout: false,
    onkeyup: false,
    onclick: false,
    submitHandler: function() {
      form[0].submit();
    },      
    messages: { 
        firstName:{
            required: "First Name is required.",
            minlength: "First Name entered is invalid.",
            aplhawithaposonly:"First Name entered is invalid."
        }
    }
    });
});
```

aplhawithaposonly is written in another js file

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("aplhawithaposonly", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z'\s]+$/i.test(value);
  }, "Please enter Alphabetic or apostrophe ' only.");
```

Now the page is getting validated only on submit of the form. But I want the validation to happen on blur of the field. I tried to keep onfocusout:true. But that is not solving. Can someone please help me how to achieve this?
This is the js file that is being used jquery.validate.min.js.
Should I use any other version of jquery for this? Please guide me..

Comment: Please do not post duplicates.  It clutters the site and it's unfair to people trying to help you.  Duplicate of [validate on field blur using jquery validate plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20855863/validate-on-field-blur-using-jquery-validate-plugin)

Answer (score 3):

**Quote OP:**

> *"...**I want the validation to happen on blur of the field**..."*

If you want validation on focus out, then why do you have `onfocusout: false` set in your options?

Validation on focus out is already the *default*, so **there is no need to set any options to achieve this behavior**.

> *"...I tried to keep `onfocusout:true`. But that is not solving. Can someone please help me how to achieve this?"*

[As per the documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate), *"boolean `true` is not a valid value"*.

> **onfocusout**
>  Type: Boolean or Function()
>  Validate elements (except checkboxes/radio buttons) on blur. If nothing is entered, all
>   rules are skipped, except when the field was already marked as
>   invalid. Set to a Function to decide for yourself when to run
>   validation.  **A boolean true is not a valid value.**

In other words, since `onfocusout` validation is already the default behavior, you are not supposed to declare this option at all... just leave it out.  Only use `onfocusout:false` when you want to disable it or `onfocusout: function() {...` when you want to over-ride it.  Again, never use `onfocusout:true` if you simply want the default behavior.

The same principal applies to the `onsubmit`, `onkeyup`, and `onclick` options.

---

Regarding this...

```
if (form.length) {
    form.validate({ 
        ....
```

There is absolutely no need to test for the form's existence before attaching the `.validate()` method to it.  **With any jQuery selector, if it doesn't match an existing element, simply nothing will happen.**

Simply put `.validate()` within the DOM ready event handler...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#yourform').validate({  // <- initializes the plugin
        // options, rules, and callbacks
    });

});
```

---

Regarding this...

```
<input class="required minlength aplhawithaposonly" type="text" id="firstName"
name="firstName" minlength="3" maxlength="40"  />
```

Since you've already declared `minlength` as a HTML5 validation attribute, there is no need for `minlength` inside of `class`.  Besides, putting `minlength` inside of `class` does not work because there's no way to pass the parameter.  Only rules that can be declared with a boolean `true` can be declared within `class`.

---

Regarding this...

```
submitHandler: function() {
    form[0].submit();
},
```

This is exactly the default behavior of the plugin... it's superfluous code, so take it out.  Only use `submitHandler` callback if you need to over-ride the default `form` action, for example, with `ajax()`.

---

Regarding this...

```
ignoreTitle: false,
```

[As per the documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate), this is already the default behavior.  Best to take it out.

Comment: @Sparky..As per ur suggestion, I have only kept onkeyup:false. So now its validating on blur of the field. But Its not removing the error message even if we enter a valid value. I have created a new post for this. Could you please check that and advice me? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878326/jquery-validate-plugin-not-removing-error-messages-after-validation